# Why pytest_generate_tests hook gives an 'fixture not found' error, while it defines a fixture?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to implement the following using external data (arguments) via pytest_generate_tests. This example works:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('case', [1,2,3,4])
def test_regression(case):
    print case
    assert True
```

Imagine, i retrieve test data via argv option. So, i've created conftest.py, added option `--data`, added fixture `data` and added `pytest_generate_tests` hook. Please pay attention, that if i do not declare `data` fixture this will not work (but in the example there is not fixture declaration): http://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html#generating-parameters-combinations-depending-on-command-line

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--data', action='store', default='', help='Specify testing data')

@pytest.fixture
def data(request):
    return request.config.getoption('--data')

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'data' in metafunc.funcargnames:
        # imagine data.cases = [1,2,3,4,5]
        metafunc.parametrize('case', [1,2,3,4,5])
```

For exampple, i have argument data, that containts itself some test data & some test cases. So, i define conftest.py the following way:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--data', action='store', default='', help='Specify testing data')

@pytest.fixture
def data(request):
    return request.config.getoption('--data')

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'data' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        # lets imagine data.cases = [1,2,3,4,5]
        metafunc.parametrize('case', [1,2,3,4,5])    

# test.py (just removed @pytest.mark.parametrize line)
def test_regression(case):
    print case
    assert True
```

The example above will give an error: fixture 'case' not found. But if i substitute `case` with `data` it will work:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--data', action='store', default='', help='Specify testing data')

@pytest.fixture
def data(request):
    return request.config.getoption('--data')

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'data' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        # lets imagine data.cases = [1,2,3,4,5]
        metafunc.parametrize('data', [1,2,3,4,5])    

# test.py (just removed @pytest.mark.parametrize line)
def test_regression(data):
    print case
    assert True
```

But i need test parameter named `case`. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I faced the nearly same problem today:

I can not give you the actual root cause but the problem seems to be that the function parameter which gets passed to the test function is expected to be a fixture. So if you are using `data` it is working as your are using a fixture.

If you are using `case` there is no fixture found for `case.`
I solved this by doing the following:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'func' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        # do some stuff
        metafunc.parametrize('func', all_combinations)

def test_function_prototypes(func):
    assert func
```

This will throw the `fixture 'func' not found` error. I solved it by adding the following lines:

```
@pytest.fixture
def func(request):
    return request.param  # pass the param to the test function
```

I didnt find something in the docs concerning the need to supply this function.

I also observed that uncommenting the fixture again lets the code still work. I guess its related to caching...